# How to set password for PostgreSQL 14.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I follow a tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-22-04-quickstart . I buy a Virtual Private Server (VPC) what use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS , 4 GB RAM, 100 GB SSD disk, 2 cores. My commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

[image]

In this case, How to set password `postgres` for user `postgres` on PostgreSQL 14.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Comment: You do not set the password to `postgres`. You are on the road to [hell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50149034/6464308).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\password <username>` when You are logged to DB, after that You will be asked to enter password twice

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the `ALTER ROLE` command to set the password.

```
 ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

<sup>***Reference:** [`ALTER ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs)*</sup>

But setting a password on the `postgres` user seems counter-productive. If you're connecting locally you have identity authentication, so a password is not needed. If you're connecting over a network the `postgres` account is a prime target for password guessing attacks, so it's better to create an alternative database superuser account and use that.

```
 CREATE ROLE mydbadmin WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'correct_horse_battery_staple';
```

<sup>***Reference**: [`CREATE ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) (PostgreSQL | Docs)*</sup>